# I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but my sound doesn't work

Tags: 20.04

I am new to Linux and I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but my sound isn't working.

I searched for some solution and tried some that I
found but nothing worked.

What should I do? Below an img with the sound settings.

Below my pc specs:

```
product: B250M-D3H (Default string)
   product: B250M-D3H-CF
         product: CMK4GX4M1A2400C14
         product: CMK4GX4M1A2400C14
         product: CMK4GX4M1A2400C14
         product: CMK4GX4M1A2400C14
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
      product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
            product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
            product: GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
         product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            product: xHCI Host Controller
               product: USB Keyboard
               product: Blue Snowball
               product: Razer DeathAdder 2013
               product: HD Pro Webcam C920
            product: xHCI Host Controller
         product: 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
         product: 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
         product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21
         product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
         product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
         product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #11
         product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #12
            product: IT8892E PCIe to PCI Bridge
         product: 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (B250)
         product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
         product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
         product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0400
      product: PnP device PNP0501
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0b00
      product: PnP device INT3f0d
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
      product: PnP device PNP0c02
         product: ST1000DM010-2EP1
         product: WDC WDS120G1G0A-
   product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

[image: sound options]

![lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Audio] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61KkO.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?   it's a little early to be using the 2024-April release... so either that's a typo, or you're using a *forgery*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you edit your question to include the brand and model of your computer? This will make it much easier to offer a specific answer for your problem. If you could also explain which solutions you may have tried, this will reduce the risk of someone suggesting the very same things. 

Comment: Are you sure that is the right output device?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the prompt reply. I have edited my question with the specs of my pc, that I got from "sudo lshw | grep product >file"

No forgery, I downloaded the latest version from Ubuntu website

Comment: Based on [this report from Linux-Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-a2f0-1458-a182&hwid=e4c366247e5d), the audio device does not work with Ubuntu 20.04. It can be detected, but that's about it.

Comment: what does that mean? I can't fix my sound? i.i

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Audio` please?

Comment: @darth_epoxy I have included an image with lspci -vvnn as asked

Comment: If you `sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel` does it return FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.?

Comment: @death_epoxy yes

Comment: OK then it's fired up and running so the problem might be the firmware. Try the usual `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` and if no change is evident then look at upgrading to a higher kernel even if not released yet (you can always go back).

Comment: hi guys, thank you for your help.
i gave up and went back to windows, then there my sound wasn't working as well..

after i unplugged and plugged my headset it was working again.. i imagine that if i had done that maybe it'd have fixed in Ubuntu as well..

Thanks again.